# Regarding double dataype

Tags: java, string, double

I have a double variable test. I want to extract the all digits before decimal point and two digits after the decimal point store the output in integer variables dollar, cents. how can i do it? I dont want any rounding to happen.

example:

```
double test= 12.1234
```

Output

```
int dollar =12;
int cents =12;

double test =1235.0
```

output

```
int dollar=1235
int cents =0
```

Answer (score 4):

For currency, especially when you don't want any rounding, you should use the `BigDecimal` class. Something like:

```
BigDecimal test = new BigDecimal("12.1234");
int dollar = test.intValue();
int cents = test.scaleByPowerOfTen(2).intValue() - dollar * 100;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Does it work for negative and non decimal values? 
 test = new BigDecimal ("-12.24") 
 test =new BigDecimal("2");
 test =new BigDecimal("-2");
 
Also i retrieve this double value from table through a custom API function. This custom API function retrieves the BigDecimal value  from the table and  does a doubleValue() returns the double value. 
I am unable to change this custom API function.  In this case if i convert into Bigdecimal and do the calculations will it cause any issues?
 test=new BigDecimal(BigDecimal.valueof(doubleval));

Comment: It works with integers and negative values as well. Precision loss takes place when the API function converts BigDecimal to double (why does it do it?). I don't think there are any options to deal with it but to work around/extend/override the API.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try your solution and let you know.

Comment: I am getting the output as dollar =12 and cents=1212. I want the cents to be 12. how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
double test= 12.1234;
int dollar = (int) test;
int cents = (int) ((test-dollar) * 100);
```

Comment: What about overflows, rounding errors and precission errors? Double is not approriate to store money.

Comment: @Thomas: Agree. BigDecimal is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
dollar = test;
test -= dollar;
cents = test * 100;
```

Line 1 assigns the integer part of test (12) to the integer 'dollar.'
Line 2 removes the 12 dollars from the test value.
Line 3 assigns 100 times the fractional part of test to cents.  Note that I don't round here.  For that, you'd have to:

```
cents = (test + 0.005) * 100
```

Comment: Line 1 would need a integer cast, else you'll get possible loss of precision error.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. Rather than printing the values, you can simply assign them as you see fit.

```
double d = 32.456;
System.out.println( (int)d );
System.out.println( d-(int)d);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] s = Double.toString(test).split(".");
String dol = s[0];
String cent = s[1].substring(0,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For double values greater than `10^13`, there won't be ANY significant digits after the notional decimal point.

You should not be using `double` or `float` for representing financial quantities.  Use `int` or `long` (appropriately scaled and with explicit checks for overflow) or `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @arav - Overflow is when a number is too large (positive or negative) to be represented in the data type being used in the calculation.  For example, if you are using a Java `int` and add 1 to the largest representable `int` value (`2^31 - 1`), then the computation will *silently* overflow and you will get a negative result; i.e. `-2^31`